# python — Converting a string into python list 2

Tags: python

I want to convert string in python

```
INPUT : 
s = ["'UIS006538'"]
```

I want output to be

```
OUTPUT :
s = ['UIS006538']
```

how can i do that?

Comment: Please clarify. When you say the output is `s = ['UIS006538']`, do you mean you want the exact text `s = ['UIS006538']` to be printed to the screen? Or do you want the variable `s` to be equal to the list `['UIS006538']`? Or something else?

Comment: Why are all the answers here downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your input, you can strip the character `'`

```
>>> s[0].strip("'")
'UIS006538'
>>> [i.strip("'") for i in s]
['UIS006538']
```

You can alternatively use an `eval` to get all such strings

```
>>> [eval(i) for i in s]
['UIS006538']
```

Comment: please see input and output in my question

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: s = ["'UIS006538'"]

In [2]: s = [s.pop().strip("'")]

In [3]: s
Out[3]: ['UIS006538']
```

Short way:

```
In [4]: s = ["'UIS006538'".strip("'")]

In [5]: s
Out[5]: ['UIS006538']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `filter` as follows:

```
s = [filter(lambda x: x != "'", s[0])]
```